# Blank / Empty Values of Key and Value retrieved in the Mapper class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have written a MapReduce code for running it on a CDH4 cluster. My requirement was to read the complete file as the value and the file name as the key. For that I wrote custom InputFormat and RecordReader classes.

Custom input format class: FullFileInputFormat.java

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

import FullFileRecordReader;

public class FullFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<Text, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf jobConf, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        reporter.setStatus(split.toString());
        return new FullFileRecordReader((FileSplit) split, jobConf);
    }
}
```

And the custom RecordReader class: FullFileRecordReader.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class FullFileRecordReader implements RecordReader<Text, Text> {

    private BufferedReader in;
    private boolean processed = false;
    private int processedBytes = 0;

    private FileSplit fileSplit;
    private JobConf conf;

    public FullFileRecordReader(FileSplit fileSplit, JobConf conf) {
        this.fileSplit = fileSplit;
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Text createKey() {
        return new Text("");
    }

    @Override
    public Text createValue() {
        return new Text("");
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        return processedBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = fileSplit.getPath();

        if (!processed) {
            key = new Text(filePath.getName());

            value = new Text("");
            FileSystem fs = filePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(filePath);
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes = 0;

            while ((numBytes = fileIn.read(b)) > 0) {
                value.append(b, 0, numBytes);
                processedBytes += numBytes;
            }
            processed = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Though whenever I try to print the key-value in the RecordReader class, I get their values, but when I print the same in the mapper class, I see blank values for them. I am unable to understand why the Mapper class is unable to get any data for keys and values.

Currently I have only a Map job and no reduce job. The code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

import FullFileInputFormat;

public class Source {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws java.io.IOException {
            System.out.println("Processing " + key.toString());
            System.out.println("Value: " + value.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf job = new JobConf(Source.class);
        job.setJobName("Source");

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setJarByClass(Source.class);
        job.setInputFormat(FullFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        JobClient.runJob(job);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating new instances in your next method - hadoop re-uses objects so you are expected to populate the ones passed. It should be as simple as amending as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean next(Text key, Text value) throws IOException {
    Path filePath = fileSplit.getPath();

    if (!processed) {
        // key = new Text(filePath.getName());
        key.set(filePath.getName());

        // value = new Text("");
        value.clear();
    }
```

I would also recommend pre-sizing the value text to avoid 'growing' pains of the value's underlying byte array. Text has a private method called setCapacity, so you unforntunately can't call it - but if you used a BytesWritable to buffer the file input, you can call setCapacity in side your next method, passing the fileSplit length (note this may still be wrong if your file is compressed - as the file size is the compressed size).

Comment: Another thing - you should override the isSplittable method for your input format and make sure it returns false (your current record reader doesn't pay any attention to the offset and length of the file split)